# Knockout one way binding from model to view

Tags: knockout.js

Using Knockout, is it possible to set up one-way binding such that changing the view model will update the view, but updating the view won't update the view model?

I am using a routing engine to get parameters from the URL, to fetch data from a source, to populate a view model, to populate a form (view). But, I don't want to update the view model when the user changes the form values - I want them to "submit" the form, which will update the URL, which will trigger the routing engine...

I have tried `data-bind="textInput: MyValue"`, which updates the view model per keystroke,  `data-bind="value: MyValue"`, which updates the view model when the form element loses focus, `data-bind="attr: {value: MyValue}"`, which works for the initial bind, but then changing the view model's value does not update the view.

Are there any default bindings that will do what I want? Any other approaches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute a property in knockout binding is becomes a one way/read only. So in the following model for example:

```
var Person = function(data){
    var self = this;
    self.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
    self.LastName  = ko.observable(data.LastName);
    self.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
        return self.FirstName() + " " + self.LastName()
    });
}
myData = { FirstName: "John", LastName: "Smith" }
var me = new Person(myData);

ko.applyBindings(me);
```

I can make FirstName a one way/read only property simply by executing it in the binding:

```
<input data-bind="value: FirstName()">
<input data-bind="value: LastName">
<label data-bind="text: FullName"></label>
```

So now the first input only gets the value and can not set it but the second input will have two way binding and will update the LastName property.